# JQuery object selection returning double set of images

Tags: jquery, object, dynamic-arrays

I am working on a product page where I have an array of additional product images displayed under the main product image. I load these additional images in the code behind and display the first 4 images with chevrons to scroll through these additional images 4 at a time. The problem I encountered while debugging the JQuery that scrolls through these images was that my each() loop had a double set of images returned from the selector. The strange thing was that the correct number of images would display; it would not display the second set but in my logic where I would hide the right chevron when I reached the last image I had trouble determining that I was at the last selection. Here is the code for the right chevron click where I had problems:

```
    $('.chevright').unbind('click').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var dsply = $('.chevright').css('display');
    if (dsply === 'none') {
        return;
    }
    var imgcount = 0;
    var imgdisp = '';
    var foundinline = 0;
    var imgclass = '';
    var imglast = $('.addlimgdiv img').last().attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    var lastdisp = '';
    $('.addlimgdiv img').each(function () {
        imgdisp = $(this).css('display');
        if (imgdisp !== 'none') {
            foundinline = 1;
        }
        if (foundinline === 1) {
            if (imgdisp !== 'none') {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                imgcount++;
                if (imgcount < 5) {
                    var newclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
                    if (newclass > imgclass) {
                        debugger;
                        $(this).show();
                        imgclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // Don't go past the last image and hide chevron if last group of images
    debugger;
    if (imgcount < 5) {
        $('.chevright').hide();
    }
    if (imgclass === imglast) {
        $('.chevright').hide();
    }
    $('.chevleft').show();
    return false;
});
```

Here is a screenshot of an inspect on the page showing 9 images:
[image]

Here is a screenshot with an additional variable showing how the selection doubles the images:

[image]

If anyone has any ideas I would like to learn what I am doing incorrectly to have the array double up like shown. I do have additional JQuery doing a zoom feature and clicks on each additional image to replace the main image display.

I can provide additional code if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: A selector is not going to double elements in the DOM.  Since you are doing `$('.addlimgdiv img')` that suggests that you have 18 elements that match that selector in your entire document.  You should see the same thing with `document.querySelectorAll('.addlimgdiv img')`

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have multiple products on that page?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did not notice that this is actually showing up twice on the page source. I was sure I checked this yesterday. It must be that this asp.net control page is being loaded twice. But your advice has been extremely helpful.